# Visual Studio 2010 QuickWatch window not visible

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I highlight a variable in VS2010 and right click to choose QuickWatch, the QuickWatch window does not appear.  VS behaves as though the modal window is open and keeps me from doing anything until I hit "Cancel".

A coworker suggested that I go to the Window menu and choose Reset Windows Layout but that didn't help either.

BTW, I am running on Windows XP.

Comment: Does it show up on the start bar? If so, you can right click the window, hit move, and then use the arrow keys on the keyboard to move it around until you find it. It sounds like maybe it's off of the viewable area of the screen.

Comment: No it doesn't.  It's a modal window that is subordinate to the VS app.  I think you are right about it being off the viewale area of the screen but so far I can't think of a solution

Comment: What Cancel button are you clicking on?

Comment: Yep, in my case it was that Snagit Shortcut, thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try opening the Quickwatch window (Shift+F9 by default), then press Alt, then press twice on the Down key. finally press the Enter button.

This should activate the move action for the window. Now try playing with the arrow keys, or with your mouse.

Answer (score 16):

For the benefit of others, the Visual Studio Shift+F9 keyboard shortcut suddenly and mysteriously stopped working for me recently and after searching around for quite a while, I just finally tracked it down to the "Snagit" (version 11) app. The Snagit tray app uses Shift + F9 globally in Windows to start a video capture:

[image: Default Snagit settings]

This overrides the Visual Studio keyboard shortcut... So I have now disabled the Snagit shortcuts in Tools>Program Preferences by selecting "None" for the dropdown key setting for all except the first one ("Print Screen"):

[image: My Snagit settings]

I hope this helps someone save some time!

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have a solution for you:

Go to `Tools`**->**`Options`**->**`Environment`**->**`Keyboard` and set the Window.Dock shortcut to something you will almost never use. I tried `SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+]`

Then go to your View and click on QuickWatch so it has focus. Press whatever shortcut you used in the previous step!

This worked for me, and hopefully it does for you, as well!

**EDIT**: wcm is right that this does not work if you're looking specifically for the QuickWatch window because it steals focus and is a different sort of window than many of the others in VS. I am able to manipulate the window, even if off-screen, in Windows 7 by holding the windows key and then pressing the arrow keys. Up maximizes it and left and right move it in that direction in half-screen increments.

Comment: I went in with high hopes but it didn't work for QuickWatch.  It did work for other windows like Find and Replace.  Where did QuickWatch dock for you?

Comment: @wcm Ah you're right the QuickWatch window is different. I'm on Windows 7, what OS are you running? If I click on QuickWatch and it grabs focus I can do the WindowsKey+ArrowKey to move it around. Up usually brings it to full screen, and left/right will move it across my monitor in half-screen increments. Down will minimize it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm running XP and the Windows/Arrow key thing doesn't work for me

Comment: @wcm Have you tried to right click on the Visual Studio icon in the start bar and click on move and use the arrow keys after you have activated the QuickWatch window? That *should* work in XP, as it is the analog to what I'm doing in Win7

Comment: That didn't work either.  When I right clicked it gave me nothing.  +1 for trying.  I'm sure that this would have worked perfectly if I had been using Win7.  Thanks for the effort.