# Visual Studio Keyboard Shortcut of quick watch (shift + F9) Not Working

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, resharper

My quick watch (<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>) shortcut suddenly is not working.
But its alternate keyboard chord <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> works fine.

And all other shortcut seems working fine. But quick watch is the only one that I currently found.

I have tried other shortcut with Shift or with F9 , no problem.

I am also using Resharper, is that affecting VS Shift F9?

Comment: have you tried resetting  the keyboard scheme ?

Comment: Have you installed other tools like Resharper that could have stolen that combination?

Comment: @emoreau99 no, i am pretty sure. Resharper is the only one.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you have Snag-It installed on your machine, its global shortcuts may override application specific shortcuts in Visual Studio (or other apps).

See @nuri's answer here: [Visual Studio 2010 QuickWatch window not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795702/10714144) for instructions and screen-shots to change the Snag-It settings.

In the meantime, just go into the Snag-It preferences, the HotKeys tab, and set the "Video capture start/pause/resume" hot key to something other than [Shift]-[F9]. For myself, I only use "Global capture", so I set everything else to "None".

Comment: YOU ROCK! My case was SnagIt

Comment: I was 11 months into this problem, I would never imagine it was because of snagit. Thank you!

Comment: I've been many years into this issue and while researching extended keypresses such as F24 (done by Shift - F12) I read this and the light went off; I've been using VS for 20+ years and always did Shift-F9, until it stopped; seems like 10 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

In `TOOLS` --> `Options` | `Keyboard`, make sure the right mapping scheme is selected (Visual C# 2005 for me) and click Reset and finally, Ok

Comment: when i reset VS all setting , this get reset too , and I even tried reset this alone, no luck either way.